# RocketMQ nameserver start error -- Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, rocketmq

I was trying to install RocketMQ from scratch following [the official guide](https://rocketmq.incubator.apache.org/docs/quick-start/), I used jdk 1.8.0_121 and maven 3.5.0.

However, after the step `mvn -Prelease-all -DskipTests clean install -U`, there was no directory `distribution` generated, so the `cd distribution/target/apache-rocketmq` wouldn't succeed.

Then I tried to directly start the nameserver by typing `sh bin/mqnamesrv`, and it gave me the following error.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=320m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the DefNew young collector with the CMS collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.rocketmq.namesrv.NamesrvStartup
```

I had thought it might be the problem of my CLASSPATH environment variable, but it still didn't work even if I set it. Below is my configuration

```
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/src/jdk1.8.0_121
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export MAVEN_HOME=$HOME/src/apache-maven-3.5.0
export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

Is there any update to the source code or some extra step that does not appear on the document yet, I wonder if I missed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to bring you trouble, please git clone the newest source code in `develop` branch, and there is a independent module `distribution`.

While please `cd target/apache-rocketmq-all/` to run rocketmq if you are in `master` branch.

Comment: And we have polished the guide, please check it, thanks.

Comment: Hi xinyu, thanks for your anwser, it works for `develop` branch. One little problem with `master` branch is that the `apache-rocketmq-all` directory is not automatically generated.

Comment: I managed to start it in `master` branch by copying all the `*.jar` archives into a single directory `lib`, including those from the [bin-release.zip](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=incubator/rocketmq/4.0.0-incubating/rocketmq-all-4.0.0-incubating-bin-release.zip) and those generated during build, and it was able to start after that. So maybe the real problem is the missing packages? I'm not sure because I'm a newbie in Java. But anyway, switching to `develop` branch sounds more reasonable.